# vb.net: Get to resources of a referenced project

Tags: vb.net, image, resources, reference, my.resources

I have a project which contains all custom controls and images; we'll call it projectBase.  Now I have created a windows forms project (project1) that references projectBase.  I need to access the embedded resource (images) of projectBase in project1.  Any idea how i can pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to expose the images as readonly properties of your custom control classes.

Answer (score 5):

In project properties, under Resources, you have the Access Modifier at the top, which you can set as Public. Now you can access resources from the other project like this:

```
Dim someResource = MyReferencedProject.My.Resources.SomeResource
```

Comment: this is exactly what i am looking for, but i am having trouble locating the access modifier.  All i see is a type filter, add resource, remove resource, and view options at the top.

i forgot to mention i am using 2005, could this be the difference?

Comment: I'm using VS2008... looking at the documentation it seems to be new to 2008 unfortunately. But check out the answer to this question, there are some other ways to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140937/is-there-a-way-to-make-strongly-typed-resource-files-public-as-opposed-to-intern