# I want to get list from .resx file

Tags: c#

I have my .resx file in another solution folder and i want to get list or array of items from it  ..

Comment: What did you try? What was the result?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`ResourceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx) class.
If you want more details, please tell us what youre trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide public accessible methods to you resx files, the automatically created accessors (Properties.Resource.Value) are scoped to internal.

So to access resources from another project you will have to create a class in the project where the resource is located and give it a public property that maps to your resource value.

**Edit:**

So you never stop leaning ... the above is correct but not the best way ... see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140937/is-there-a-way-to-make-strongly-typed-resource-files-public-as-opposed-to-intern) to make all strings/values in a resouce file publicly accessible.

Comment: He appears to want an array containing all of the resources.

Comment: can you write me little example ?

Comment: @l_beka_l: You need to tell us exactly what you're trying to do, and where your file is.